# display javascript result with php if condition

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

magento site : **www.1234.com** . In this page : **www.1234.com/site6/orders.php** We are trying to display **Javascript** result inside **php if else** condition

when we tried below code, **If condition** result is displaying , but else condition result is not displaying, also when i tried this code in else part : `echo "display";` , than also result did't displayed.

```
function getDesignerCollection()
    {
    $user_home = new USER();
    require_once '../../app/Mage.php';

    Mage::app();

    $accountType = $rows['type'];
    if ($accountType == "admin")
        {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
            'nin' => '0'
        ));

        }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var colsOption = [    
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'15',renderer : my_renderId},   
    {id: 'created_at' , header: 'Order Date' , width :'120'},
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'75'},
    {id: 'product_id' , header: 'Product Id' , width :'70'}


     ];";
    echo "</script>";
    }
    }
```

here magento related code is displaying, but php & javascript code is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Mage::app();

$accountType = $rows['type'];
if ($accountType == "admin")
{
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('designer_id', array(
        'nin' => '0'
    ));

}
else
{
?>
<script>
var colsOption = [    
{id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'15',renderer : my_renderId},   
{id: 'created_at' , header: 'Order Date' , width :'120'},
{id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'75'},
{id: 'product_id' , header: 'Product Id' , width :'70'}


 ];
</script>
<?php
}
}
```